# Wiping a laptop's hard drive from BIOS

Tags: windows, windows-xp, dban

I am trying to wipe an old laptop's hard drive. It doesn't have a CD drive, so I have been using a USB flash drive to try and wipe the hard drive from the BIOS.

I have been using [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) which I installed as an ISO on the USB flash drive. Whenever I try to boot into this I get an error saying: `No operating system`.

Does anyone know of a way to wipe a hard drive?

I also tried to boot into safe mode, but it gets stuck in a endless loop.

Comment: You are confused as to what the 'BIOS' is. You aren't trying to wipe your system from BIOS, you are simply trying to boot into a different operating system from the one installed on your system.

Comment: Ah right ok. How do I go about wiping the hard drive then? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't configured your computer to boot from USB. Exactly how you do so will depend on your specific computer. Sometimes, it's F12 or ESC as you are booting.

Comment: When you created the USB drive, did you actually create it as a bootable one? There's more to it than copying some files from an ISO to it.

Comment: BIOSs used to be able to do low level formatting of hard drives.  I havent seen this feature in a *very* long time